# Tableview context menu: custom animation from row to a preview view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, contextmenu

I have implemented row-specific context menus for a tableview, which includes a simple preview view controller, as shown below.

[image: Screen recording showing context menu]

I would like to implement a transition or animation so that the icon (a `UIImageView`) in the tableview animates into position as the icon in the preview view controller.

However, looking at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontextmenuinteraction) (in particular `UITargetedPreview` and `UIPreviewTarget`), I can not figure out how to create such an animation in the context of a tableview with multiple rows.

---

The preview view controller is generated using an icon from the data model depending on the row, as shown below:

```
class DrugPreviewViewController: UIViewController {
    private let imageView = UIImageView()

    override func loadView() {
        view = imageView
    }

    init(item: CustomItem) {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

        // Set up image view
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.backgroundColor = .clear
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: item.icon ?? "defaultIcon")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate).tinted(with: Color.colors[item.iconBackgroundColor ?? 0])
        // Preview to have the same aspect ratio as the image
        preferredContentSize = UIImage(named: item.icon ?? "defaultIcon")!.size
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

The shortened context menu code is shown below:

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, contextMenuConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {

    // Selected Drug and notes
    let selectedItem: CustomItem = dataArray[indexPath.row]

    var notes = selectedItem.notes ?? ""
    var titleString = selectedItem.name

    // Code for menu items and actions
    // Defines actions array
    // Omitted for brevity

    let actionProvider: UIContextMenuActionProvider = { _ in
        return UIMenu(title: titleString, children: actions)
    }

    return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: indexPath as NSCopying, previewProvider: {
        return CustomPreviewViewController(item: selectedItem)
    }, actionProvider: actionProvider)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a native Cocoa solution without having to make my own detailed transitions, thanks to an [article by Kyle Bashour](https://kylebashour.com/posts/context-menu-guide).

It seems that all of the standard single-view context menu `UIContextMenuInteractionDelegate` methods have equivalent `UITableViewDelegate` methods for when you are implementing context menus in a tableview.

I managed to achieve the result shown below. It does not animate the icon into the preview in the middle, but it is close enough to what I want and looks much better than what I had before.

[image: Desired outcome screen capture]

To achieve this, I needed to make `previewProvider` nil in the code above that returns the context menu:

```
return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: indexPath as NSCopying, previewProvider: nil, actionProvider: actionProvider)
```

Then I had to implement these two delegate methods - both call the same block of code to return a `UITargetedPreview`:

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, previewForHighlightingContextMenuWithConfiguration configuration: UIContextMenuConfiguration) -> UITargetedPreview? {
    return makeTargetedPreview(for: configuration)
}


@available(iOS 13.0, *)
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, previewForDismissingContextMenuWithConfiguration configuration: UIContextMenuConfiguration) -> UITargetedPreview? {
    return makeTargetedPreview(for: configuration)
}

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
private func makeTargetedPreview(for configuration: UIContextMenuConfiguration) -> UITargetedPreview? {
    guard let indexPath = configuration.identifier as? IndexPath else { return nil }
    // Get the cell for the index of the model
    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? DrugTableViewCell else { return nil }
    // Set parameters to a circular mask and clear background
    let parameters = UIPreviewParameters()
    parameters.backgroundColor = .clear
    parameters.visiblePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: cell.iconView.bounds)

    // Return a targeted preview using our cell previewView and parameters
    return UITargetedPreview(view: cell.iconView, parameters: parameters)
}
```

`cell.iconView` is the `UIImageView` in my custom `UITableViewCell`.

---

Please note, for safety in the event of the table data changing as the menu is being displayed, Kyle recommends using the actual data model (accessed with the index path) to get the data needed for the preview (rather than the cell). See his article for more information.

Comment: Thank you. Save my day.

Comment: @PowHu Glad it helped!

Comment: Why is it accepted as a correct answer? `configuration.identifier as? IndexPath` requires you to use `contextMenuConfigurationForRowAt` you skipped and somehow pass `IndexPath` which doesn't comform to `NSCopying` which is required!

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov The code `indexPath as NSCopying` achieves this through casting.

Comment: Be aware that this escapes `indexPath` beyond the scope where it's valid.

Answer (score 1):

I think implementing the protocol `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` could put you in the right direction. It's a bit complicated first. Here is an example how to do this

https://github.com/dasdom/DDHCustomTransition/blob/master/DDHCustomTransition/Transition/CustomTransition.swift

Comment: Thanks very much for the advice - I’ll check it out. I wasn’t aware of that protocol.